# Get PHP Echo in Android

Tags: php, android, androidhttpclient

I have some problems with Receiving PHP Echo message from an website.
I have this code:

```
HttpClient httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient(); 
   HttpPost httppost=new  HttpPost("http://www.itbstudios.tk/test.php");
   HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
   String str =  EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

I found this code and a lot more here on stackoverflow and is is not working. The app is crahsing on `httpclient.execute();`

Internet permission is set in android manifest.

Php code is just an `<?php echo "test"; ?>`

I'm building for API 15 and testing on HTC Device.

Can you guys help me?
I even created an other project and paste the code in on create and i have the same problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the error you are seeing in LogCat?

Comment: When I try to go to http://www.itbstudios.tk/test.php it doesn't load and times out. It helps if the server is working first.

Comment: It's probably a NetworkOnMainThreadException...

Comment: it an other error was NetworkOnMainThreadException

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HttpClient got some bugs in API higher than 10. Use HttpUrlConnection instead.

GET method example:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.itbstudios.tk/test.php");
HttpUrlConnection mUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
mUrlConnection.setDoInput(true);

InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(mUrlConnection.getInputStream());
String s = readStream(is);
```

Comment: instead of using readstrem(is), use    s = IOUtils.toString(is);

Comment: @Panache Referencing a non-standard class you didn't include is no different than referencing a custom method that was not included.