# File does not upload on server android

Tags: java, android

I tried many methods how load image on server and not one showed any errors. And nothing helped me. Pictures are not uploaded to the server. The file path to image is correct. I also tried to change the file path on the server, it also did not help me and added permission to access files, this did not help.

load file:

```
public class UploadFiles {
    private String sourceFileUri = "";

    public UploadFiles(final String sourceFileUri){
        this.sourceFileUri = sourceFileUri;
        new UploadFileAsync().execute("");
    }

    private class UploadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                HttpURLConnection conn = null;
                DataOutputStream dos = null;
                String lineEnd = "\r\n";
                String twoHyphens = "--";
                String boundary = "*****";
                int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
                byte[] buffer;
                int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
                File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

                if (sourceFile.isFile()) {

                    try {
                        String upLoadServerUri = "http://myserver/gpstracker/api/v1/users/uploadfile.php";

                        // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(
                                sourceFile);
                        URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                        // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
                        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                        conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                        conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                        conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE",
                                "multipart/form-data");
                        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                                "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                        conn.setRequestProperty("bill", sourceFileUri);

                        dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"bill\";filename=\""
                                + sourceFileUri + "\"" + lineEnd);

                        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

                        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                        while (bytesRead > 0) {

                            dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                            bufferSize = Math
                                    .min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0,
                                    bufferSize);

                        }

                        // send multipart form data necesssary after file
                        // data...
                        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens
                                + lineEnd);

                        int serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

                        String serverResponseMessage = conn
                                .getResponseMessage();
                        System.out.println("SERVER: " + serverResponseMessage);
                        if (serverResponseCode == 200) {
                        }

                        fileInputStream.close();
                        dos.flush();
                        dos.close();

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                } // End else block


            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "Executed";
        }
    }

}
```

php file

```
<?php

 if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['bill']['tmp_name'])) {
    $uploads_dir = '/var/www/html/gpstracker/api/v1/users/images';
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['bill']['tmp_name'];
    $pic_name = $_FILES['bill']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $uploads_dir.$pic_name);
  }
    else{
     echo "File not uploaded successfully.";
  }  
?>
```

Server response:

> System.out: SERVER: OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server replies 200 does not mean the upload is succuessful. Try to output the php echo. See [Get PHP Echo in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055147/get-php-echo-in-android).

Edit: Do you have permission on that directory? See [PHP move_uploaded_file() error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501749/php-move-uploaded-file-error)

Comment: I/System.out:  File not uploaded successfully.

Comment: Thx very much! I haven't permission ))